# Change name of the image upload

Tags: php, image, upload

i have a file to modify my profile but i need name change of the imagem during the upload.
I need this to be no substitutions images already in the folder when I upload.

Code of my file is:

```
<?php
include 'verificar.php';
require_once 'config.php';

$id = $_GET["id"];
$nome    = $_POST["nome_perfil"];
$email   = $_POST["email_perfil"];

// Configuração da Imagem
$imagem  = $_FILES["imagem_perfil"];
$destino = "img/perfil/".$imagem['name'];

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    if(empty($nome) || empty($email))
    {
        header ("Location: index.php?page=erro");
    }
    elseif(empty($_FILES['imagem_perfil']['name'])) 
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE utilizadores SET Nome='$nome', Email='$email' WHERE ID='$id'");
        header ("Location: perfil_completo.php");
    }

    else
    {

        mysql_query("UPDATE utilizadores SET Nome='$nome', Email='$email', imgPerfil='".$imagem['name']."' WHERE ID='$id'");

        if($imagem['type'] == "image/jpeg"){
            move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'] , $destino);
        }else if($imagem['type'] == "image/png"){
            move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'] , $destino);
        }else if($imagem['type'] == "image/gif"){
            move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'] , $destino); 
        }
        header ("Location: perfil_completo.php");
    }
}
?>
```

**Now the solution:**

```
<?php
include 'verificar.php';
require_once 'config.php';

$id = $_GET["id"];
$nome    = $_POST["nome_perfil"];
$email   = $_POST["email_perfil"];

 // Configuração da Imagem
 $imagem  = $_FILES["imagem_perfil"];
 $array = explode(".",$imagem['name']);
 $destino = "img/perfil/".$id.".".end($array);

 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

 if(empty($nome) || empty($email))

     {
     header ("Location: index.php?page=erro");
     }

 elseif(empty($_FILES['imagem_perfil']['name'])) 
 {
     mysql_query("UPDATE utilizadores SET Nome='$nome', Email='$email' WHERE ID='$id'");
     header ("Location: perfil_completo.php");
 }

     else
     {

 mysql_query("UPDATE utilizadores SET Nome='$nome', Email='$email', imgPerfil='".$id.".".end($array)."' WHERE ID='$id'");

 if($imagem['type'] == "image/jpeg"){
    move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'] , $destino);
 }else if($imagem['type'] == "image/png"){
    move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'] , $destino);
 }else if($imagem['type'] == "image/gif"){
    move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'] , $destino); 
 }
header ("Location: perfil_completo.php");
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want the file to be renamed if there is already a file in your upload directory with the same name?

Comment: No, i want to rename any file is uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change this:

```
$destino = "img/perfil/".$imagem['name'];
```

to this:

```
$result = mysql_query("Select Nome from utilizadores WHERE ID='$id'");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$yourName = $result['Nome'];

$array = explode(".",$imagem['name']);
$destino = "img/perfil/".$yourName.".".end($array);
```

The `explode()` is to get the image sufix.

---

You can set the name into the `$yourName` variable

Comment: How to i change the name of the imagem to ID of the user ? Can you help me to do this ?

Comment: The name has chanhed but stay "18JPG". On the database name has not changed

Comment: Ohh, i fixed it. I had forgoten to add the `.` into the filename

Comment: Yes, its fixed. Now the database. In my query how to i put this name ?

Comment: Add a simply sql statment to get the username...
If you dont konw how, pleas add your user-table to the question

Comment: name of the id is "ID" and the query stay in the question.

Comment: Dinistro, i follow in the Insert. When i submit an image, the name is the same of the image, not the ID of the user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51447/discussion-between-dinistro-and-luismiguelgt)